# Is it possible for a designer to develop an AngularJS UI without the developer involved?

Tags: angularjs

In Silverlight, you can have UX person develop the UI look and feel seperatly and then developer can take the XAML and implement the behavior. In this model, UX person can create mock data for UI and verify the behavior independent of the implementation. As a developer, we do not need to worry about XAML and focus on implementing the behavior. I like this model, which encourages the independent development yet with collaboration.

Is such separation possible in AngularJS? If possible how would one go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically this is possible, but AngularJS does not have the toolset to create markup in a drag & drop interface like expression blend does. If you want to quickly prototype user interface designs with Angular you'll have to get your hand dirty. This doesn't mean the designer has to be a hardcore javascript developer; you can easily mock resources and replace them with full functional code at a later point.

I did have an Angular project a few months ago where the users themselves and some not-so-experienced-developers had to create custom forms: [this is what I ended up with](http://embed.plnkr.co/L0n4qi/preview).